# VS 2010 asp tags not recognized

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010

Edit: The error I'm getting is that VS intellisense is not recognizing asp tags. Specifically it is saying "unrecognized namespace 'asp.'" I should have included that.

I have literally scoured the internet and have found no solutions that have worked for me. I am using VS 2010 SP1 and ASP tags do not work for any project on any page. The solution deploys just fine and everything works, it just doesn't like my asp tags and I get no intellisense. Here's a list of things I've done so far in no particular order:

- Deleted "Reflected Schemas" folder
- Reset settings
- Deleted the contents of the "10" folder under app settings
- Deleted the .suo file
- Deleted the bin and obj folders
- Restarted VS
- Restarted the virtual machine
- Repaired the VS installation
- Uninstalled and reinstalled VS
- Commented out the Register TagPrefix
- Rebuilt
- Unloaded and Reloaded the project
- Right-clicked and hit properties of each of my .dll's in windows explorer to see if any of them were locked
- Prayed to/made ritual animal sacrifices to several pagan gods

I'm working on custom sharepoint web parts so I have no master page and no config file. If it is a result on the first 3 pages of a google/stackoverflow/codeproject search for anything similar to the title of this post, I have probably tried it. If anyone can think of anything I haven't tried yet PLEASE let me know.

Comment: What do you mean by "It doesn't like my tags"? Is the source code displayed in the browser?

Comment: Specifically "unrecognized namespace 'asp.'" I should have included that.